# Is the set $E=\{(x,y):|x|>0,|y|\geq 0\} \subset \mathbb R^2$ open or closed?

Tags: general-topology

I am learning about open and closed sets in a functional analysis course.

I want to know if the set $E=\{(x,y):|x|>0,|y|\geq 0\} \subset \mathbb R^2$  is open or closed or clopen.
It is clearly clopen because the set $S = \{(x,y): x>0, y>0\}\subset \mathbb R^2$ is open and the fact that $|x|>0$ *and* $|y|\geq 0$ implies it cannot be inside or outside a ball.

However, I am not sure how I would write this as a proof?

As another example of a set, I know if i were to prove that $S = \{(x,y): x>0, y>0\}\subset \mathbb R^2$ is open I would just show that the ball $B((x,y),r) \subset S$ hence S is open, but I don't understand how to show that something is neither open nor closed and how I would lay such proof out.

I have just started a functional analysis course and just grasping the concept of open and closed sets so any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding the set. $E=\Bbb R^2\setminus\{(x,y):x=0\}$.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: $E$ is the coordinate plane less the $y$-axis.

Comment: This is just a question from my course book..

Comment: There are other sets called F, G ect

Comment: In other words, the complement of the $y$-axis.

Comment: You mean that is the set? I don't know why you have written I have "misunderstood" the set, I have simply stated a question and said I am confused about how to lay the answer out. You could have written that in English.

Comment: I added a different example in my question, I did not think that was the set, if you read my question.

Answer (score 1):

To show something is not something else, you need to prove its not something else. You want to show it's not open or closed. So first show its not open: there exists a point $(x,y)\in E$ such that you can't find an open ball around that point fully contained in $E$.

To show its not closed, either show it's complement is not open, or use the sequential definition of closed: all convergent sequences have their limit points contained in $E$.

Comment: Thanks, I am unsure as to how to show that its compliment is not open, as surely its compliment would be neither open nor closed too hence just as confusing for me to prove still? Excuse my bad understanding.. Also, I have to use the ball method to prove this, and not the method of convergent sequences. Could you please explain how I would show that its compliment is not open? Many thanks

Comment: @user212237: First, very carefully, write down the expression for the complement in terms of some inequalities. It should be fairly obvious from there on.

Comment: The compliment is the set $\{(x,y):|x|\leq0,|y|< 0\}$. Is this not clopen too?

Comment: @user212237: forget about clopen. Look at what you're trying to show: that this complement set is not open which would imply the original set is not closed since the complement of closed is open.

Comment: Careful with your wording: the fact that the *complement* is not open means the original set is not closed. On the other hand saying "it's not open hence must be closed" is wrong. Sets are not doors. To write it, find a point in the complement that doesn't contain a ball, in other words a ball of any radius won't work at that point.

Answer (score 1):

I am getting your set as follows(check)

$\{(-\infty,0)\cup(0,\infty)\}\times \mathbb R$

i.e $\mathbb R \setminus\{0\}\times \mathbb R$

which is open as it is cartesian product of open sets

How is it closed,I dont think so

because consider the sequence $(\frac{1}{n},0)$ converging to $(0,0)$ does not belong to $E$

Comment: hey, sorry not it is definitely neither open nor closed..

Comment: Also, this is not the set I am looking at.

Answer (score 1):

Note that since $|y| \ge 0$ for all $y$, we have $E = \{ (x,y) | x \neq 0 \}$.
If $(x,y) \in E$, then $B((x,y), {1 \over 2}|x|) \subset E$, so $E$ is open.

It is clear that the sequence $({1 \over n},0) \in E$ for all $n$ but the limit ($(0,0)$) is not. Hence the set is not closed.

Comment: Hey, thanks for this. Im a little confused, where does the $\frac{1}{2}$ come from? many thanks

Comment: I just need to find some ball such that the containment holds. Any $r$ such that $0 < r \le |x|$ would do. Draw a picture.

Comment: @user212237, for every point $\langle x, y\rangle$ in $E$ there is always a point closer to the $y$-axis that is also in $E$; let's arbitrarily pick half-way closer.  $\forall \langle x, y\rangle\in E : \langle \tfrac 1 2 x, y\rangle\in E $.  So $E$ is open.